# Login with API post json headers

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate")
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
    req.Headers.Add("username:" + TextUser.Text)
    req.Headers.Add("password:" + TextPass.Text)
    req.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim response1 As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response1.GetResponseStream
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
    Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Close()
    MsgBox(contents)
End Sub
```

i want to use the username:(user), password:(pass) in the headers just as in the documentation
https://wiki.vg/Authentication

and the msgbox to see if it is working but all the time i get the response 400 (incorrect request)
pls help me

Comment: `HttpWebRequest.Headers.Add()` just add regular HTTP headers. The docs clearly indicate that you should send a JSON string with the request, but you aren't. You've got to construct a JSON string containing the data and send that in the request body.

Comment: do you have any example code? just to help me bcuz i'm begginer

Comment: Stack Overflow is unfortunately not a coding/tutorial service. You are expected to do [quite a bit of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593) before asking here. You already know how to read from the response stream; there's a respective stream in the request for sending data. As for the JSON: That's literally just concatenating a couple of strings together. Pretty much like you already do with your current headers, only longer.